# Differing Reponse Codes from Django Application

Tags: python, django, python-requests

For both `GET` and `POST` requests I simply want to print the associated `QueryDict` in my test view:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    print request.GET

if request.method == 'POST':
    print request.POST
```

When I make `requests` using both methods I get different response codes. I could use some help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post request has triggered Django's [CSRF protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/) so you are getting a 403 Forbidden response.

Usually, it means that you need to include the CSRF template in your template.

In this case, because you are making requests from the shell, it might be appropriate to use the `csrf_exempt` decorator on this view to disable the CSRF protection.

Comment: There's an example in the [docs I linked to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#utilities)

Comment: Now I'm getting a 500 error response code with the decorator.

Comment: If you're in debug mode, the `content` of that response will have the traceback. Do `response = requests.get()`, then `response.content`. Nobody can tell what the problem is simply from '500 error response'.

Comment: That's not going to help. I'm redirecting first off. Secondly, a 500 code is a 500 code.

Comment: I fixed it. The error was the decorator. I didn't import it.

Comment: Could you please help me with another interrelated issue, please?

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? A response with a 500 status code can still have contents, and I'm not sure what difference it makes whether you redirect or not.

Comment: You still there? I fixed the CSRF. Please help with this.

Comment: My `POST` request using a dictionary body doesn't work either.

Comment: That's an unrelated problem, you'd be better asking a new question. However, note that `{'name', 'Malik'}` is not a valid dictionary.